# C#: return stong types from reflection

Tags: c#, dynamic, types, casting

In the latest version of C#, is it possible to convert a dynamic type to a strong type, if you know the type in advance?

I'm using reflection to call a method on an object, which returns to a var:

```
var returnVal = context.GetType().InvokeMember(MethodName, BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, context, lParams.ToArray());
```

I can easily get the type being returned to `returnVal`. Is it possible to cast\convert thins to a more strongly typed version?

**EDIT FOR CLARITY:**

In this situation, I know the type being returned but only by string. To get the type, I have to do:

```
diAssemblies[k].GetType(diAssemblies[k].GetName().Name + "." + returnType)
```

Where `returnType` is the name of type being returned.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to get the result of the method invocation in to a strongly typed field.

**CONTEXT**

I'm loading assemblies containing .edmx files from a directory, then invoking methos on those contexts. At run time, the loader won't know what assemblies it's going to be loading. However, the person using the loader will be aware of the assemblies, methods and types.

This is to create a generic wrapper around database calls through entity framework (with stored procedures), that will be reused elsewhere.

Comment: Are you *actually* using `dynamic` or not? `var` and `dynamic` are entirely different, and it's not clear what you mean.

Comment: If you only know it as a string at execution time, how can you possibly expect it to be strongly typed at compile time?

Comment: I don't know about the difference it would make here. I'm using `var` right now, but there's nothing stopping me using `dynamic` if it'd get the job done

Comment: Well it's not at all clear what you're trying to do with the return value. If you only know the type at execution time, what could you do with the value? Please give us more context.

Comment: That's exactly why I wanted to check if it was possible or not! My gut feeling was that it's not, but people around these parts are pretty damned good with the language

Comment: @AndyBursh On a side note, var is just a language keyword, when it is compiled it is replaced by the type returned by whatever's on the right hand of the = sign.  So if the invoke member method returned "dynamic", it would be exactly the same as dynamic, I suspect, given that it looks like you're using reflection, that it will return an object.  If you use the dynamic (Case Sensitive) keyword instead, you will then be able to call methods as if you had the concrete type, but if the method doesn't actually exist it will throw a run time error.

Comment: @AndyBush: You should read up on what `var` is and what `dynamic` is, because you are mixing and confusing things here.

Comment: @AndyBush You will probably get more relevant answers with by changing the question title to ask about returning strong types instead of objects, since you currently aren't using dynamic at all.

Comment: Will change the title, thanks.

So the general consensus here is that I'm confusing `var` and `dynamic`? Is it worth continuing down this path, or should I go back and rework the design?

Comment: I'd suggest you probably are fine continuing down this path, although I'd need more info to be certain.  You do need to read about generics though, since they are highly applicable, and you may wish to look at the dynamic keyword for curiosity.  Once you understand both concepts you may decide to re-work your design, or you may feel that you are going in the right direction and just need to incorporate what you've learnt

Comment: Thanks a lot! Looks like I've got some bedtime reading to do.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't know the Type statically, how could you use a statically typed reference?  What you *can* do is have the returned type implement an interface you do know about statically, then cast to that interface.

So, if MyStrongType implements IMyStrongBehavior, you can cast the return value to IMyStrongBehavior and use that statically.  The underlying value is already strongly typed, regardless of whether you cast it.

Alternately, you can store the return value in a `dynamic` variable (which will allow you to invoke known methods without an actual statically-typed interface.)  The disadvantage here is that you don't get any Intellisense and any mistakes you make won't show up until runtime.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't get the advantages of a concrete type such as compile time checking and intellisense.  This is because you are only actually working out what the type is at run time.  It is late bound, which means that it's a job for dynamic and the DLR.  You can cast it to an object that you know the actual object will inherit from (e.g. object), but you can't cast to the actual type.  You might want to look into generics as an alternative if you had for example:

```
public T GetReturnVal<T>()
{
   return (T)context.GetType().InvokeMember(MethodName, BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, context, lParams.ToArray());
}
```

You would at least be returning a concrete type to callers of type T.  But this type has to be set at compile time, i.e. known in advance.

I recomend you read [An Introduction to C# Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) as it does exactly what, from the context you've added, you need to do.

Comment: Ack! Sorry, that was really bad of me. I didn't explain properly. Let me update my post.

Comment: You could also check that typeof(T) matched up to the type you were expecting within the method and throw an exception or handle as appropriate.

Comment: In addition, if you know that the type will impliment certain interafaces, or inherit from a certain base class (e.g. EntityObject), you can place
where T:EntityObject
after the parameters in the method title to further constrain the types which can be used.